# Checkbox doesn't show as checked in UI when checked property set to true in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some checkboxes in a table that is being generated in an `ng-repeat`.

The checkboxes are defined like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkView{{::myObj.TeamId}}" 
    ng-disabled="disableView(myObj)" 
    ng-click="setViewSelection(myObj.TeamId, this.checked)">
```

The checkboxes have no `ng-model` attribute and this was intentional. I wanted to control the `checked` status of each checkbox directly through javascript.

For some reason the checkbox doesn't respond to it's `checked` property being updated in javascript. So if I have this statement in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('chkView27').checked = true;`
```

It will work programmatically, I can do

```
console.log(document.getElementById('chkView27').checked);
```

And it will print `true` to the console. But the UI in the browser doesn't reflect that. In the browser the checkbox remains unchecked. I've verified that nothing else is affecting the `checked` property of the checkboxes after the fact. The UI just doesn't update. Why is this?

EDIT: As per prasad's suggestion I tried wrapping the statement in `$scope.$apply` like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    document.getElementById('chkView27').checked = 'checked';
});
```

But this just causes angular to throw an "Action already in progress" error.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest

Comment: If its angular application the you should be using `ng-model` here..

Comment: @PankajParkar I can't use ng-model here without a lot of refactoring so I'd like to find a solution with vanilla javascript.

Comment: try using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click` would provide correct value

Answer (score 0):

Set the checked attribute to the string "checked" as well:

```
document.getElementById('chkView27').checked = 'checked';
```

Comment: Tried that as per your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. Interestingly, after setting the `checked` property to 'checked', this `console.log(document.getElementById('chkView27').checked);` returns `true` and not `checked`.

Comment: As i said "checked" as well, try do both:
document.getElementById('chkView27').checked = true;
document.getElementById('chkView27').checked = 'checked';

Answer (score 0):

DOM manipulation done in javascript directly wont affect DOM, because it is unknown to angular. If you are doing this in controller directly, it will work. But if you are doing it in plain javascript then you need to use $apply to let angular know that you have made changes in DOM and then angular will update that for you.

Comment: I am doing this in a controller, but it's still not affecting the UI. I'm looking at $apply now...

Comment: I tried `$scope.$apply` but it didn't work. See my edit above.

Comment: Will you post jsfiddle for your code, because I tried doing on my own and it worked for me.

Comment: It is throwing error because $digest is already running, you should check $scope.$$phase before using $apply, as this flag is set true when digest cycle is running. Please post simple jsfiddle or plunker for it.